# c# how to add infomation to a highscore class

Tags: c#, .net, list, addition

I'm currently trying to make a HighScore class but unsure how do it properly. This is the code so far:

```
class HSItem
{
    private string name;
    private int points;

    //Constructor Method
    public HSItem(string name, int points)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.points = points;
    }

    //Property for name
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    //Property for points
    public int Points
    {
        get { return points; }
        set { points = value; }
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
public class HighScore
{
    //Method HighScore constructor for list cap
    public HighScore(int maxInList)
    {
        List<int> topHS = new List<int>(maxInList);
    }

    //Method for Add
    public void Add(string name, int points)
    {
        List<HSItem> hs = new List<HSItem>();
        hs.Add(new HSItem { Name = name, Points = points });
    }
}
```

But I get this error `'HighScore.HSItem' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments` which leaves me clueless.

The `Highscore` constructor is to take in a number to determine the maximum space the list can have and the `Add()` method is to add new information to the first class.

I appreciate the help

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem..

Comment: Actually, if you have any knowledge of what the constructor is, I find the error message to be very clear. You've defined a constructor that takes arguments. Yet when you create an instance of that class, you are not providing any arguments. That's an error.

Answer (score 4):

You are not passing anything to the constructor. You could do the following:

```
List<HSItem> hs = new List<HSItem>();
hs.Add(new HSItem("Darren", 1000));
```

Or define a constructor that takes 0 arguments:

```
public HSItem()
{

}
```

Comment: Please edit the answer (add a space or so) so I can retract it. I really should stop reading too fast, missing subtle details.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I have edited it.  It would be useful if you commented first and then down voted (Just to indicate that there was something wrong with my answer)

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace this line

```
hs.Add(new HSItem { Name = name, Points = points });
```

by the following one

```
hs.Add(new HSItem (name,points));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a constructor but you're not using it. If a class has a constructor then it removes the default no parameter constructor, meaning you can't use `new HSItem()` because there is not a constructor that takes 0 arguments any more.

Change

```
hs.Add(new HSItem { Name = name, Points = points });
```

To

```
hs.Add(new HSItem(name,points));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the constructor call syntax with the property initializer syntax.

As several have pointed you, the way to call your constructor is this:

```
new HSItem(name, points);
```

The code you wrote:

```
new HSItem { Name = name, Points = points };
```

is really just a convenient shorthand for this:

```
var item = new HSItem();
item.Name = name;
item.Points = points;
```

Comment: +1 for explaining what is really happening using an object initializer.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a class with no constructor the class will automatically get a constructor with no parameters. However if you define a constructor with parameters the one with no parameters will NOT be added automatically. If you want a constructor without parameters you should add it yourself. Alternatively I'd suggest you to remove your constructor which you aren't using anyway:

Remove this piece of code and all will be good:

```
//Constructor Method
public HSItem(string name, int points)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.points = points;
}
```